# Firebase newest feed for following users

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, angularfire

I'm working with Angularjs and Firebase. Right now I'm new at firebase for this I'm struggling to find solutions for my issues.

Imagine I'm sorting users like this

```
users:{
    facebook:123456789:{
        blog: [{
            // List of blogs
        }],
        following: [{
            // List of users auth.ids
        }]
    },
    facebook:123456780:{
        blog: [{
            // List of blogs
        }],
        following: [{
            // List of users auth.ids
        }]
    }
}
```

And getting logged in user blog object and iterating and pushing it to the array like this

```
var blogRef = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl + "/users/" + authData.uid + "/blog");
var userBlog = $firebaseArray(blogRef);
var userBlogDatas = []
blogRef.limitToLast(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var snap = snapshot.val();                
    userBlogDatas.push(snap);
});
```

So far everything working fine.

But how can i get latest blogposts from feeds from following users. Right now I have some idea which represents getting user blog datas and pushing them into array. I'm not sure is it right way or not...
[image]

I also read https://github.com/firebase/firefeed/blob/master/www/js/firefeed.js code but I could not get any information for myself.

Any ideas will be really helpfull.

Thank you

Comment: Can observers be set up for each of the followers blog nodes? Their auth_id's area available in the 'following:' node so that would be easy. Or.... and maybe this isn't how your app is set up:  Since each user has a set of followers, won't each of those followers in-turn have their own set of followers? i.e. If user_a posts a blog post and user_b is notified, and assuming user_b has a follower, user_a, won't user_a be notified of users_b's post?

Comment: When every user is registered they will be stored under the users/auth_id json path and if the user post new posts they will be stored under the users/auth_id/blog and if they follow some other user their id will be stored under the users/auth_id/following And I want to if one of the following user post something they should be appear follwing   feeds

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. Your user node shows who they are following in the following: node. Can an observer just be added for each of the the users' blogs they are following?  The ref would be /following/user_id/blog

Comment: no in the following ref it only contains user_id

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of ways to do this if I am understanding the question correctly.

One way is that instead of storing the user_id, store the user id as a key and the blog id as the value like

```
users
    facebook:123456789
        blog
            // List of blogs
        following
            user_id_0: blog_id_x
            user_id_1: blog_id_y
```

Then you can add an observer to each blog in the following node. You can get the path from the key/value pair. In this case Facebook:123456789 is following:

```
/users/user_id_0/blog/blog_id_x
/users/user_id_1/blog/blog_id_y
```

Another option would be to create a child node within the following node that contains two values: the user_id and blog_id.

```
users
    facebook:123456789
        blog
            // List of blogs
        following
            follow_id_0
              userid: user_id_0
              blog: blog_id_0
            follow_id_1
              userid: user_id_0
              blog: blog_id_1
```

In this  case, facebook:123456789 is following user_id_0's blog 0 and blog 1

Note: user_id_0 and user_id_1 are actually Facebook:abcdefg users id's