# How to model a timeline that automatically adds post from every follower on firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am building a social app, I have a database on firebase that is structured like this:

```
tJWRbfqUUbSQn5eI8ZS5vPG9znr1

  bio:

  coverPhotoUrl:

  email:

  firstname:

  imgUrl:

  lastname:

  name:

  phone:

  posts

    -KPN0b7QmNp8AjYy4yFl
    -KPXmtvZdiQ--QjZ-j3m
    -KPc7PpDkmFNU9JjlIJP
    -KPc7PptOulQdrpsrGEp
    -KPc7Pq6JC7bjt8-sRFU
    -KPc7PqJ2651EIQWXIv6
```

the top level key is th user id, so i have that for every user, each user has posts too, inside the posts node, i have comments, pushed in the exact the same way as posts.
My question is that I am a bit curious about how i am going to model a Newsfeed, right now A Newsfeed to me is a list of posts from you and your everyone you are following in the exact order of the time they were posted while a timeline is just posts from the said user in that order too.

I have correctly done the timeline by just iterating over posts from the user
I have tried to do the Newsfeed part in two ways, which has bugs and I think is not very efficient

1. Since every user maintains a list of his followers in his own node, i made it such that anytime a user makes a post, he not only writes in his own 'posts node' but also in every other person following him's 'Newsfeed' node

   Cons of this method
   a. in the event of an unfollow, i am not able to remove user A's posts from User B's timeline
   b. i am giving every user access to write in every other person's node, which as i have read, is not a very good practice.
2. Maintain the url of User A's post node in user B's Timeline node, which would solve the con B of method 1.

Cons of this method
a. I dont know how to implement it.

I dont know if there is any textbook way to do this(of course there has to be, there is only so much social network platforms out there), if there is i want to know, also if you could point me to how(not help me to) implement my method 2, i will very much appreciate it.

Also, i was following  [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593378/firebase-newest-feed-for-following-users)

which does not completely answer my question but looks like a very interesting approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is referred to as client-side fan-out. This Firebase Blog post provides a great explanation and will point you in the right direction.

[Client-side fan-out for data consistency](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for, thank you so much

Comment: No problem...glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a new datastructure for keeping score who is following who. Use that information to build your newsfeed. That way there is no need for one user to write "into" another user. Every posting is only stored once for the user why created the post. If the follow and unfollow changes, you can simply recalculate on the fly which posts to include in a newsfeed

Comment: I think i understand, ill try and implement this. thanks